# Non primitive lfsr sequence

Tags: algorithm-design, random-number-generator, finite-field, lfsr

Given a non-primitive LFSR sequence (i.e number of states is less than $2^n - 1$); how do we find out the the characteristic polynomial? Will Berlekamp-Massey algorithm work in this case?

for example; for the following sequence-

[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

the repetition period is $105$. Applying the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm returns

$X^7 + X^6 + X^5 + X^1 + 1$

Doing manually gives me a different answer.
Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

Adding what I did manually:

I found the primitive polynomials and took LCM to confirm the $Berlekamp-Massey$ output.

To check, I represented the polynomial as $11100011$ ; took the first seven bits of the sequence and did the $and$ operation with the polynomial. took the $xor$ of the output and appended that output to the initial 7 bits and continued. This is what I did to crosscheck the answer I received. It is here I went wrong probably.

Answer (score 4):

A binary sequence of period $105$ will have characteristic polynomial 
that is a *divisor* of $x^{105}-1$. Since $x^{105}-1$ has irreducible
factors of degrees $12, 4, 3$, and $1$, it is *possible* to have an LFSR
of length $4+3=7$ generate a sequence of period $105$, and that is
exactly what has happened here. Note that
$$x^7+x^6+x^5+x+1 = (x^3+x+1)(x^4+x^3+1)$$
where $x^3+x+1$ and $x^4+x^3+1$ are irreducible (in fact, primitive) polynomials of degrees
$3$ and $4$. Individually, the shorter LFSRs generate sequences of
periods $7$ and $15$: the "product" sequence has period 
$\operatorname{lcm}(7,15)=105$.

Answer (score 1):

Berlekamp Massey, correctly implemented, always gives the right linear complexity for a periodic sequence. There is a good resource online, [magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), which has an implementation, if you want to check what you're doing wrong. Click on the Cryptography chapter on the Handbook link and look under the last section for a Berlekamp-Massey command and an example on how to call it (need to use GF(2) as your field, as in the example).

Edit: Magma calculator confirms the polynomial above.

Comment: I think it is better if you include the code here. AFAIK SageMath.cell fails the Berkalamp-Massey no the Deskop.