# What is the result of not connecting the 1st register to the xor gate in LFSR?

Tags: encryption, keys, random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, lfsr

I designed 8 bit lfsr in vhdl. According to mathematical theory, I xor processed the outputs of registers 1, 4, 5, 6 and 8 and connected them to the input of register 1. theory says that if I give the inputs the polynomial "10111000", I get the repetition of (2^8)-1.

I tried some more. And I tried the circuit without connecting the output of the 1st register to the xor gate. interestingly I got the same (2^8)-1 repetition again. however, this time every 8-bit polynomial containing a 1-bit "1" signal produced the same signal. For example, when I gave "00100000" to the inputs, I got the same signal again.

What I'm wondering is why when I bind the output of register 1 to the xor gate I only get the repeat (2^8)-1 with 1 polynomial, while I get it with every polynomial when I don't?

[image]

[image]

Comment: By "give the input the polynomial 01000" you mean the loading of the LFSR? The question is unclear. Draw a diagram. Or state what the characteristic polynomial is, and what is the numbering of LFSR bits that you are using. It is absolutely impossible to get a full period when you disconnect register 1 [which is at one end] since you no longer have an LFSR of length 8.

Comment: I added 2 images. If I make my circuit as in the first image, I get a repetition of (2^8)-1 when I only give the correct polynomial (ie P= x^8+ x^6 + x^5 x^4 +1) to the register inputs. My circuit works perfectly.

If I make my circuit in the second image, no matter what polynomial I give to the inputs (for example, P= x^3+ x^2 + x^5 x^7+1) I get the loop of (2^8)-1.

Whereas, if I only give the correct polynomial in the first circuit, I get a loop of (2^8)-1.

Comment: so I think if your described behaviour is correct something is wrong with your circuits or VHDL code.

Comment: Yes that's true. It was due to a problem in VHDL code. I solved the problem with some fiddling.

Comment: I am glad that you sorted it out. You can accept the answer if it was satisfactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it is a question of what the connection polynomial is, the figure helps clarify what you are doing. In both cases the polynomial is degree 8.

Originally, your connection polynomial is
$1+x+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^8$ (I wrote it in the order of the LFSR connections). This polynomial is not primitive, it's not even irreducible, with the factorization
$$
1+x+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^8=(x+1)^2(x^4+x^3+1)(x^2 + x + 1)
$$
so there is no question of obtaining the full period of $2^\text{degree}-1=2^8-1$ from it. Depending on the loading it will give shorter periods but never full period. See this question [Non primitive lfsr sequence](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33447/non-primitive-lfsr-sequence) for more info on what periods are possible.

When you change the connection you have the polynomial
$1+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^8$ which has no factorisation into a product of lower degree polynomials (so it is irreducible). This polynomial is actually primitive and will give a maximum possible length sequence with period $2^8-1.$

See also [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register). I have used the following commands on  [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) to check these properties.

> R:=PolynomialRing(GF(2));
> f:=1+x+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^8;
> IsPrimitive(f);
> Factorisation(f);
> f:=1+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^8;
> IsPrimitive(f);
> Factorisation(f);

with output

> false

> [
> <x + 1, 2>,
> <x^2 + x + 1, 1>,
> <x^4 + x^3 + 1, 1>
> ]

> true

> [
> <x^8 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1, 1>
> ]

Gadiel Seroussi has given a very long list of primitive polynomials up to degree 10,000 [here](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf).

Comment: Addition: [Jörg Arndt](https://www.jjj.de/) has lists of binary [primitive](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-primpoly.txt) and [irreducible](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-irredpoly.txt) polynomials to degree 11. Note: All binary irreducible polynomials have an odd number of terms including high-order and 1 (the later corresponding to the output of the XOR in the convention of the answer). This is equivalent to an even number of inputs to the XOR. Thus counting the 5 inputs to the XOR is enough to disprove that the first drawing yields (minimal) period $2^8-1$, regardless of initial state.